# Calling printf of C in MASM assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, printf, masm, masm32

I'm having problems invoking the print function two times, one right after the other (for some reason, is acting weird)
In this code, I defined a proc that invokes the print. I call two times this proc but it prints just the first time (the second time prints nothing)

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 200h
option casemap :none
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
dll_dllcrt0 PROTO C
printf PROTO C :VARARG

.DATA
_2 DW 2
_3 DW 3
_x@main@print_proc DW ?

.CODE
print_proc PROC
invoke printf, cfm$("%hd\n"),_x@main@print_proc
RET
print_proc ENDP

START:
MOV BX,_2
MOV _x@main@print_proc,BX
CALL print_proc
MOV BX,_3
MOV _x@main@print_proc,BX
CALL print_proc
END START
```

[image: Console printing only once, the second invoke did nothing]

In this one I call the proc first, assigned the var and printed it, and after that I printed it again. Just like before, the second print didnt work

```
....
.DATA
_2 DW 2
_3 DW 3
_c@main DW ?

.CODE
_print@main PROC 
MOV BX,_3
MOV _c@main,BX
invoke printf, cfm$("%hd\n"),_c@main
RET
_print@main ENDP
START:
CALL _print@main
invoke printf, cfm$("%hd\n"),_c@main

END START
```

[image: Console printing only once, the second invoke did nothing]

Finally, I invoked the print two times in the main: as you can see it's print fine but the second time it prints garbage at the end.

```
...
.DATA
_2 DW 2

.CODE
START:
invoke printf, cfm$("%hd\n"),_2
invoke printf, cfm$("%hd\n"),_2

END START
```

[image: Console printing twice, but adding garbage]

Comment: You might need an `invoke exit, 0` or a `RET` in `START`. Note the last picture shows it printed twice correctly.

Comment: It worked for the last code (where i call two times in the main one right after the other) but it didnt work for the other two codes